# Why does Qt use reinterpret_cast rather than static_cast for void*?

Tags: c++, qt

You can cast to/from any pointer to T to/from void* with a static_cast, why does Qt use reinterpret_cast?

```
int SOME_OBJECT::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    _id = QMainWindow::qt_metacall(_c, _id, _a);
    if (_id < 0)
        return _id;
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        switch (_id) {
        // Why reinterpret_cast here??
        case 0: on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested((*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        default: ;
        }
        _id -= 1;
    }
    return _id;
}
```

Comment: that title is very confusing. could we have more details please?

Comment: Significant edit, yes.  I probably saved it from being closed before you could do it yourself.  Hopefully I got it right.

Comment: This code sample is generated by `moc`, right?

Comment: Yeah, except I changed the object name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I've never been able to figure it out either.  The `void **` structure is created the same way, simply casts an `int*` to `void*` and then performs this weird cast on the other side.  As far as I can tell, static_cast would not only be fine, it would be better.

You'll find that there's a lot of questionable code in large projects like Qt.  Sometimes stuff slips through review or just sticks around because nobody wants to go through the hassle of changing it.

Comment: In other words, they didn't know any better and nobody cared to fix it.

Comment: Realize that Qt was created before what we know as "modern C++" today has really appeared, so they probably really didn't know any better. It's way too expensive (in terms of time and manpower) to go back and reimplement the framework (and not break existing applications) to use less questionable code, especially since Qt code almost always depends on the `moc` tool.

Comment: @Insilico: They are breaking compatibility with every major version though so that's not important.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I'd disagree with the consensus. You should not be able to use `static_cast` to cast from any type to `void*`, you do that only with `reinterpret_cast`. `static_cast` is reserved for types that are supposedly compatible, some compile time checking is performed (ie derived classes, numeric types between them).

From this link [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f6c9f8h.aspx):

```
dynamic_cast      Used for conversion of polymorphic types.
static_cast       Used for conversion of nonpolymorphic types.
const_cast        Used to remove the const, volatile, and __unaligned attributes.
reinterpret_cast  Used for simple reinterpretation of bits.
```

Comment: I think you're getting this wrong... You can, always, implicitly cast **any** pointer to `void*` by simply assigning to it. Also, the question is about the other way around... casting *from* `void*`.

Comment: Well yes, you can. But you should not. Isn't that support for legacy C code ? In my mind good-style C++ should use `reinterpret_cast` to warn the user that this is a pontentially tricky pointer conversion. Use of `static_cast` would be misleading, implying that there is some relationship between the two types, which is always false when one of the types is `void*`.

Comment: I disagree. The C++ standard explicitly guarantees that a `static_cast` from a pointer to object to a `void*` and back to the _original_ pointer type is safe, but using a `reinterpret`_cast` might produce a different result.